# rq.job.Job returning a 'sh: 1: mv: not found' error

Tags: python, http, request

I currently have a master python script which launches 6 jobs on remote hosts, and polls whether the jobs are done or not over a long period (days, usually). However, in my code below, the first element in the *self.job_results* list is always ''sh: 1: mv: not found'. However, the 6 job values always are in that list (e.g. there are 7 elements in the list, and there should only be 6). It appears that `rq.job.Job` is returning this value; any idea why?

```
hosts = HOSTS.keys()
job_ids = []
for host in hosts:
    r = requests.get(HOSTS[host] + 'launch_jobs', auth=('admin', 'secret'))
    job_ids.append(r.text)
host_job_dict = dict(zip(hosts, job_ids))
print "HOST_JOB_DICT: %s " % host_job_dict
launch_time = datetime.datetime.now()

self.job_result = []
complete = False
status = [False]*len(hosts)
host_job_keys = host_job_dict.keys()
while not complete:
    check_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    time_diff = check_time - launch_time
    if time_diff.seconds > JOB_TIMEOUT:
        sys.exit('Job polling has lasted 10 days, something is wrong')

    print "HOST_JOB_KEYS %s " % host_job_keys
    for idx, key in enumerate(host_job_keys):
        if not status[idx]:
            host = HOSTS[key]
            j_id = host_job_dict[key]
            req = requests.get(host + 'check_job/' + j_id, auth=('admin', 'secret'))
            if req.status_code == 202:
                continue
            elif req.status_code == 200:
                self.job_result.append(req.json()['results'].encode('ascii').split())
                status[idx] = True
    complete = all(status)
    time.sleep(1)
```

And on the server side of things...

```
@app.route("/check_job/<job_key>", methods=['GET'])
@requires_auth
def check_job(job_key):
    job = Job.fetch(job_key, connection=conn)

    if job.is_finished:
        data = job.return_value
        json_data = jsonify({"results": data})
        # return Response(response=json_data, status=200, mimetype="application/json")
        return json_data
    elif job.status == 'failed':
        return "Failed", 202
    else:
        return "Not yet", 202
```

Comment: I don't see a `job_results` list. Do you mean `self.job_result`?

Comment: sorry, yes. I edited the code to sanitize it a bit and goofed. It is indeed self.job_result.

Comment: `sh: 1: mv: not found` is an output from shell. The offending code might lie on whatever HOST is in position 0. Maybe your $PATH is screwed or something. Take a look at `print "HOST_JOB_KEYS %s " % host_job_keys` maybe, How many host job keys are there? Are you getting back a 200 with `sh: 1: mv: not found` as the contents?

Comment: I've limited running this job to just one host for debugging purposes, and printing HOST_JOB_KEYS indeed gives back the correct host name/number. If I print the results of ```req.json()['results']``` under the check for status == 200, I get back the sh error printed first, followed by all of the expected results

Comment: if `req.status_code == 200` and you are getting back the string above, then you have a server sending you back that value. Try running the executing code on that server and see what happens (whatever happens when you reference the url `check_job/`).

Comment: I guess the last bit of advice I can give is regarding the line where you do req.json. If all you are getting back is a string, then your code will raise a `JSONDecodeError`. If it is valid json, it will not raise an error (in which case, your omitting some stuff from above).

Comment: It turns out that on our server side, we are grabbing data via the above edited code (using ```from rq.job import Job```), which must be returning the ```mv``` error.

Comment: Probably the error is before even that, but I'd say your on the right path. Good luck! (again, this is a shell error, not python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be an extremely convoluted issue where `mv` and other commands in `/bin` aren't being recognized. To get around this, we just were explicit and used `/bin/mv`instead. We believe this issue cropped up as a result of a complication from a systemctl instantiation